# django admin panel sort order display

Tags: python, django

I want to change the sort of my models in the admin panel with django. For example, I want to have the "categories" on the top of the list.

How can I do that?

```
class SongAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'artist', 'album', 'slug']
    list_filter = ['created_date']
    search_fields = ['name', 'artist__name', 'album__name']
    
    class Meta:
        model = song

admin.site.register(song, SongAdmin)
admin.site.register(categories)
admin.site.register(album)
admin.site.register(artist)
admin.site.register(PlayList)
admin.site.register(PlayListSongs)
admin.site.register(discount_codes)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHq67.jpg)

Comment: Is [this](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/set_ordering.html) answering your question?

Comment: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/set_ordering.html

Answer (score -1):

you will need to add ordering to your meta,
for example

ordering = ['name']

Comment: no bro i want to change the root admin panel order list . not list of a model